# DataGrid with a CheckboxColumn does not register SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF. It binds using MVVM to a ViewModel. It works fine with just DataGridTextColumns that display information regarding my List of objects that the DataGrid binds to. Clicking a row selects it, and this works too, firing off a series of events that allow me to work in depth with the given row and derived information.

I then added a DataGridCheckBoxColumn so I can select items and remove them from my List if needed. This, However, breaks everything. Note, that ViewModel remains unchanged entirely and the SelectedItem event for the DataGrid does not seem to fire at all now. Can anyone help so I can still retain my old functionality but also retain my column of checkboxes that help the user quickly do what he/she needs to do?

Relevant XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="ArticlesOverviewDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Project.Articles}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"   SelectionMode="Single" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="65" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DgchStyle}" Binding="{Binding IsDuplicate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Duplicate" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxColumnElementStyle}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DgchStyle}" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnElementStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DgchStyle}" Binding="{Binding Author}" Header="Author" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnElementStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DgchStyle}" Binding="{Binding PublicationDate}" Header="Publication Date" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnElementStyle}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding ShowProject}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

Again, it all works if I remove the checkboxcolumn, meaning it messes with selecting an Item in the DataGrid, but I cannot seem to find any relevant information on WHY it breaks or how to circumvent this issue.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="65" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DgchStyle}" Binding="{Binding IsDuplicate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Duplicate" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxColumnElementStyle}"/>
```

Comment: What is in your ViewModel?

Comment: Everything previously there. Including the BOOL the checkbox binds to. The checkboxes work fine, and alter the same bool when selected/deselected. It literally just killed the SelectedItem functionality.

Viewmodel is far too long to paste into a reply btw, just tried. The entire thing is available for download over at lisa.codeplex.com, however, it's the WorkOnProject / WorkOnProjectViewModel in LiSAClient.WpfClient.Views/ViewModels that is causing the problem (tou should be able to see the code by navigating through the codeviewer on CodePlex)

Comment: Sounds like the checkbox is the one catching the click event. The data grid is not aware that a click was made and therefore it's not changing the selected item. there are many possible ways to solve this. It would be easier to help you if you edit your post with the relevant viewModel code ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a template column and set it's `DataTemplate` with a checkbox instead:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="65" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DgchStyle}" Header="Duplicate" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxColumnElementStyle}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsDuplicate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```